# LINQ Group by doesn't return the result as expected

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have an animal class:

```cs
public class Animals
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and a class Cost for the cost associated with the different animals:

```cs
public class Cost 
{
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of the different classes:

```cs
List<Animals> animalList = new List<Animals>()
{
     new Animals() { Type = "Wolf", Gender = "Female", Amount = 10 },
     new Animals() { Type = "Wolf", Gender = "Male", Amount = 20 },
     new Animals() { Type = "Lion", Gender = "Female", Amount = 10 }, 
     new Animals() { Type = "Horse", Gender = "Male", Amount = 5 }
};

List<Cost> cost = new List<Cost>() 
{
    new Cost() { AnimalType = "Wolf", Cost = 1000 },
    new Cost() { AnimalType = "Lion", Cost = 2000 }, 
    new Cost() { AnimalType = "Horse", Cost = 1500 }
}
```

I want to sum the cost for each animals having a result like this:

| AnimalType | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Wolf | 30000 |
| Lion | 20000 |
| Horse | 7500 |

I've tried to use LINQ and sum like this:

```cs
var totalCost = from animal in animalList 
      join cost in costList 
      on animal.Type equals cost.AnimalType 
      group animal by animal.Type into g
      select g;
```

but this only returns Wolf (supposedly because it is the only one having two genders), but I don't understand why. How can I write the `select` to find what I am looking for?

Comment: Your sample code initialises a list called `cost`, but your join references `costList`. Are you referencing the correct list?

Comment: Please post real code. You cannot have a property with the same name as the enclosing class.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your current LINQ query returns the `animal` data (`g`).

Instead, when grouping, a new dataset containing `animal` and `cost` data should be constructed in order to allow you to perform the calculation in projection.

```cs
List<CostModel> costList = new List<CostModel>() 
{
    new CostModel() { AnimalType = "Wolf", Cost = 1000 },
    new CostModel() { AnimalType = "Lion", Cost = 2000 }, 
    new CostModel() { AnimalType = "Horse", Cost = 1500 }
};

var totalCost = (from animal in animalList 
           join cost in costList 
           on animal.Type equals cost.AnimalType 
           group new { Animal = animal, Cost = cost } by animal.Type into g
           select new 
            {
                AnimalType = g.Key,
                Cost = g.Sum(x => x.Cost.Cost * x.Animal.Amount)
            }).ToList();
```

```cs
public class CostModel 
{
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

While there are few errors in your code:

1. In the LINQ query, `join cost in costList` but there is no declaration for the `costList` variable.
2. You will get error in `Cost` class as there is `Cost` property which clash the class name.

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vlaaDm)

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to adjust my code according to your suggestion, but I have the same issue as before (only Wolves are returned).

Comment: Hi can you recreate your issue in .NET Fiddle? *Only wolves are returned*, are you using `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: I can do that. The data is different (I didn't want to use real data in this question), but it is very similar. Each animal has a food ratio which can either be Fruit or Meat and I want to calculate the total cost for food. Some animals can have both Fruit and Meat. I have adjusted the code and it now returns more than Wolves, but the sum is 0 for all animals. The fiddle is this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bkuPEZ

Comment: From your data, I don't see that you have assigned values to `FruitRatio` and `MeatRatio`. By default, these will be 0, so that's why the result is 0 for all items.

Comment: From my perspective, it seems another question to perform calculation by condition. Would be great that you should post as another question and provide the sample data & expected output.

Comment: Probably this is what you want? [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3rZaRg). You should group by `AnimalType` and `PreferredFood`, then group by `AnimalType`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that. I made a new question for this data set as well, it is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562597/linq-group-by-returns-a-sum-of-0-which-is-not-expected

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a dictionary for the cost would be better:

```
Dictionary<string,int> cost = new Dictionary<string,int> () 
{
    {"Wolf", 1000 },
    {"Lion", 2000 }, 
    { "Horse", 1500 }
};
```

Then you can use the following LINQ query:

```
var result = animalList
     .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
     .Select(x => new { AnimalType = x.Key, Amount = cost[x.Key] * x.Sum(y => y.Amount)})
     .ToList();
```

Note that the code will throw an exception if one of the animal types is not in the dictionary. If you don't want that, you can also insert a where clause:

```
var result = animalList
      .Where(x => cost.ContainsKey(x.Type))
      .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
      .Select(x => new { AnimalType = x.Key, Amount = cost[x.Key] * x.Sum(y => y.Amount)})
      .ToList();
```

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/B5gOaG

Answer (score -1):

- As per your code, you have to change the property name Cost in Cost class.
  (I changed it into cost)
- Create new class as **CostModel**.

```
    public class CostModel
    {
        public string Animal { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
    }
```

- Try this code

```
    var totalCost = (from animal in animalList
                     join cost in costList
                     on animal.Type equals cost.AnimalType
                     group new { Animal = animal, Cost = cost } 
                     by animal.Type into g
                     select new CostModel
                     {
                         Animal = g.Key,
                         Cost = g.Sum(x => x.Cost.cost * x.Animal.Amount)
                     }).ToList();
    
    
    foreach(var cost in totalCost)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cost.Animal.ToString() + ":" + cost.Cost);
    }
```

Comment: How does this differ from Yong's answer?