# LINQ Group by returns a sum of 0 which is not expected

Tags: c#, linq

I have a program like this available in this Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/bkuPEZ :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Animals> animalList = new List<Animals>()
        {
             new Animals() { AnimalType = "Lion", FoodRatio = 5, PreferredFood = "meat", FruitRatio = 5},
             new Animals() { AnimalType = "Tiger", FoodRatio = 4 , PreferredFood = "meat", MeatRatio = 5 },
             new Animals() { AnimalType  = "Giraffe", FoodRatio = 3, PreferredFood = "fruit", FruitRatio = 2 }, 
             new Animals() { AnimalType = "Piranha", FoodRatio = 5, PreferredFood = "fruit", MeatRatio = 2 },
             new Animals() { AnimalType = "Piranha", FoodRatio = 5, PreferredFood = "meat", FruitRatio = 2 }
        };

        List<Prices> priceList = new List<Prices>() 
        {
            new Prices() { FoodType = "meat", Price = 1000 },
            new Prices() { FoodType = "fruit", Price = 2000 }
        };

        var totalCost = (from animal in animalList 
           join price in priceList
           on animal.PreferredFood equals price.FoodType
           group new { Animal = animal, Price = price } by animal.AnimalType into g
           select new 
            {
                AnimalType = g.Key,
                Price = g.Sum(x => x.Price.Price * x.Animal.FruitRatio + x.Animal.MeatRatio * x.Price.Price)
            }).ToList();
    
          Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(totalCost.ToList(), Formatting.Indented));
    }
}

public class Prices
{
    public string FoodType { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

internal class Animals
{
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
    public decimal FoodRatio { get; set; }
    public string PreferredFood { get; set; }
    public string? OmnivoreMeatRatio { get; set; }
    public decimal? MeatRatio { get; set; }
    public decimal? FruitRatio { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to calculate the price of buying the FruitRatio and MeatRatio required for each animal. Some animals eats both Fruit and Meat, which is an issue I have tried to solve by spliting these up into two elements (like `Piranha` in this example).

My expected output would be:

Animal  Price
Lion    10000
Tiger   5000
Giraffe 4000
Piranha 5000

but my output using LINQ is:

```
[
  {
    "AnimalType": "Lion",
    "Price": 0.0
  },
  {
    "AnimalType": "Tiger",
    "Price": 0.0
  },
  {
    "AnimalType": "Giraffe",
    "Price": 0.0
  },
  {
    "AnimalType": "Piranha",
    "Price": 0.0
  }
]
```

Comment: Before we even get into your join (I think the group is the thing that's confusing you), I'm confused by your data model. 1) `FoodRatio` is never used? 2) Why does a Lion, which prefers meat, have `FruitRatio = 5`? A Tiger, which also only eats meat, has a `MeatRatio` however. 3) Are you just trying to represent how much of each sort of food an animal eats? If so, why not just have two properties `MeatConsumption` and `FruitConsumption`, and do away with the ratios and preferred food?

Comment: @canton7       My lists are generated by importing a file and converting these to lists of the different AnimalTypes. The lists I have on Fiddle are those I've manually created and it was an error with Lion. It should have MeatRatio. The FoodRatio in practice is what percentage of the body weight an animal needs to eat to sustain itself. For those who eats only one type of food, it is the same as the ratio of that food. Piranhas has a FoodRatio of 0.5 in my files, and 0.25 for both FruitRatio and MeatRatio. I had an issue using decimals in Fiddle so I made them integer.

Comment: Why use LINQ at all? You're working with objects, not tables. You can use a `Dictionary<string,decimal>` or `Dictionary<string,Price>` to lookup the prices for each animal a lot faster than using a `join`. LINQ isn't meant to be used everywhere or replace proper object design

Comment: `I had an issue using decimals in Fiddle so I made them integer.` fix that issue then. Decimals work just fine, there's no reason to avoid them. Replacing them with integers on the other hand is behind quite a few nasty bugs

Comment: @Cenderze OT: you can lift the computation into the grouping and do `group ( price.Price * (animal.FruitRatio ?? 0) + price.Price * (animal.MeatRatio ?? 0) ) by animal.AnimalType into g select new { AnimalType = g.Key, Price = g.Sum() }`

Answer (score 3):

In .NET,  a operand with null give a null :

```cs
decimal? result = null + 2m;
// result is null
```

In each animal, either `MeatRatio` or `FruitRatio` isn't defined, then it take the default value of `decimal?` that is null.

Then this expression return everytime null :

```cs
x => x.Price.Price * x.Animal.FruitRatio + x.Animal.MeatRatio * x.Price.Price
```

And the sum of null is zero, hence your result.

---

A solution is to define a non null value for `MeatRatio` and `FruitRatio`.

```cs
internal class Animals
{
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
    public decimal FoodRatio { get; set; }
    public string PreferredFood { get; set; }
    public string? OmnivoreMeatRatio { get; set; }
    public decimal MeatRatio { get; set; } // non nullable, the default value is zero
    public decimal FruitRatio { get; set; }  // non nullable, the default value is zero
}
```

A other solution is to adapt the expression like :

```cs
x => x.Price.Price * (x.Animal.FruitRatio ?? 0) + (x.Animal.MeatRatio ?? 0) * x.Price.Price
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to calculate the Price in the following way :

`Price = g.Sum(x => x.Price.Price * x.Animal.MeatRatio) + g.Sum(x => x.Price.Price * x.Animal.FruitRatio)`